# Creating a function from a list

Tags: email

This is a fictional message sending program I've done for practice purposes. MessageSender` is a program sending emails to customers. Currently it sends two types of email: "welcome" and "please come back" email. It's supposed to run daily and write a debug log each day if it worked or not.

How do I make a function of the code in SendWelcomeMail and call it, I tried to make one myself but I'm not sure how call the function and connect the recipients function with the customers emails in the datalayer.

```
namespace EmailSender
{
    internal class Program
    {

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Call the method that do the work for me, I.E. sending the mails
            Console.WriteLine("Send Welcomemail");
            bool welcomeEmailSucess = SendWelcomeMail();
#if DEBUG
            //Debug mode, always send Comeback mail
            Console.WriteLine("Send Comebackmail");
            bool comeBackEmailSuccess = SendComeBackEmail("ComebackToUs");
#else
            //Every Sunday run Comeback mail
            if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.Equals(DayOfWeek.Monday))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Send Comebackmail");
                comeBackEmailSuccess = SendComeBackEmail("ComebackToUs");
            }
#endif

            //Check if the sending went OK
            if (comeBackEmailSuccess == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("All mails are sent, I hope...");
            }
            //Check if the sending was not going well...
            if (comeBackEmailSuccess == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Oops, something went wrong when sending mail (I think...)");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static bool SendWelcomeMail()
        {
            try
            {
                //List all customers
                List<Customer> customers = DataLayer.ListCustomers();

                //loop through list of new customers
                foreach (Customer c in customers)
                {
                    //If the customer is newly registered, one day back in time
                    if (c.CreatedDateTime >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
                    {
                        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage m = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                        //Add subject
                        m.Subject = "Welcome as a new customer at Company!";
                        //Send mail from info@company.com
                        m.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("info@company.com");
                        //Add body to mail
                        m.Body = "Hi " + c.Email +
                                 "<br>We would like to welcome you as customer on our site!<br><br>Best Regards,<br>Company Team";
#if DEBUG
                        //Don't send mails in debug mode, just write the emails in console
                        Console.WriteLine("Send mail to:" + c.Email);
#else
    //Create a SmtpClient to our smtphost: yoursmtphost
                    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("yoursmtphost");
                    //Send mail
                    smtp.Send(m);
#endif
                    }
                }
                //All mails are sent! Success!
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //Something went wrong :(
                return false;
            }
        }
```

The datalayer

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDatetime { get; set; }
}

class DataLayer
{
    public static List<Customer> ListCustomers()
    {
        return new List<Customer>()
                       {
                           new Customer(){Email = "mail1@mail.com", CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-7)}, 
                           new Customer(){Email = "mail2@mail.com", CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)}, 
                           new Customer(){Email = "mail3@mail.com", CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6)}, 
                           new Customer(){Email = "mail4@mail.com", CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1)}, 
                           new Customer(){Email = "mail5@mail.com", CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2)},
                           new Customer(){Email = "mail6@mail.com", CreatedDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5)}
                       };
        }
        public static List<Order> ListOrders()
        {
            return new List<Order>()
                       {
                           new Order(){CustomerEmail = "mail3@mail.com", OrderDatetime = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6)}, 
                           new Order(){CustomerEmail = "mail5@mail.com", OrderDatetime = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2)},  
                           new Order(){CustomerEmail = "mail6@mail.com", OrderDatetime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2)}
                       };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to make it work isn´t a really concrete problem. What results do you get when executing the code? An exception? Any unexpected results?

Comment: The main problem is calling this function later , i'm not sure how to connect the recipients to the customers email in the datalayer class when calling the function. That's the error. So basically, how am I supposed to insert this function? @HimBromBeere

Comment: So your question is "how to combine the two methods and reduce code-duplication" and then "how to call that method"? I guess this is far too broad. Aprt from that only post the relevant code into the question. Your code is currently quite hard to understand. Furthermore you should also formati it appropriately to make it easier to read.

Comment: Okay, I've edited out the less relevant parts. But to start small, how do I call this function? @HimBromBeere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you're not using the recipients list in the SendEmail function - you're ignoring it and looping through all customers that the DataLayer returns, so change that.

If you want to keep doing what you're doing, i.e. loop through each customer and send an email directly if that customer should receive the email, then change the method to the following:

```
public static void SendEmail(string toAddress, string from, string subject, 
string body)
    {
        //Create a new MailMessage
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();

        //Add customer to reciever list
        mail.To.Add(toAddress);

        //Add subject
        mail.Subject = subject;

        //Send mail from company@info.com
        mail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(from);

        //Add body to mail
        mail.Body = body;

       // Send it or write to console depending on debug
    }
```

and invoke that instead of creating the email message in the two functions SendWelcomeMail and SendComeBackEmail.
So instead of

```
//loop through list of new customers
foreach (Customer c in customers)
{
   if (c.CreatedDateTime >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
   {
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage m = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        //Add subject
        m.Subject = "Welcome as a new customer at Company!";
        //Send mail from info@company.com
        m.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("info@company.com");
        //Add body to mail
        m.Body = "Hi " + c.Email +
        "<br>We would like to welcome you as customer on our site!<br><br>Best Regards,<br>Company Team";
   #if DEBUG
         //Don't send mails in debug mode, just write the emails in console
         Console.WriteLine("Send mail to:" + c.Email);
      ...
```

Use something like

```
string welcomeSubject = "Welcome as a new customer at Company!";
string ourEmailAddress = "info@company.com";
string bodyTemplate = "Hi {0}<br>We would like to welcome you as customer on our site!<br><br>Best Regards,<br>Company Team";

   //loop through list of new customers
   foreach (Customer c in customers)
   {
       if (c.CreatedDateTime >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
       {
           SendEmail(c.Email, ourEmailAddress, welcomeSubject, string.Format(bodyTemplate, c.Email));
```

And something similar in SendComebackEmail.

That's the easiest way to use the function, without changing the structure of your code, I can think of right now.
If you wanted to have a list of recipients (like the in version you posted), you would have to change a lot, since you have the customer email in the body of the message, and so you can't just have multiple recipients and only one body.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @kkirk, I loved your solution. Is it possible to send that email and store it somewhere else, maybe if it is later run again on the same day to check if an email hasn't already been sent.

Comment: Hi @J.Dhaik, glad it was useful to you! 
It would be a clear improvement: to store the email somewhere and have a separate concern of sending the email. If you're just doing it for learning, you can e.g. store it in a list in memory and process it on a timer for instance. In a production environment, you should of course store it in a database or similar.

Comment: Great, I will try do that. But what do you mean with " It would be a clear improvement: to store the email somewhere and have a separate concern of sending the email."? Also, how would I start by creating this list, my idea is that I would create an Email store class, create a seperate email store list where I send all the information of the email in form of an object? Then I connect them to the email classes and add a bool/if statement to check if an email has not already been sent?

Comment: It would be an improvement in terms of Separation of Concerns (read e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) in that creating the email is a separate concern from sending the email. 
What you write is basically right: Normally you'd store the email objects in e.g. a database, and have a DateTime for when the email was sent and possibly one for when the email was created. You can then check for all emails that were not sent yet and ensure that all emails will eventually be sent.

Comment: Have you any idea on how? I've implemented all the changes, feel pretty satisfied with it and now moving on to create the email store class. But I have no idea how to start.

Comment: I only have time to give you a pointer. Not sure what you mean by Email store class, but you will want a class to represent the email you want to send, which should include Subject, Body, etc, Date of creation and nullable DateTime when the mail was sent.
You'll also need an email repository class, where you have a list/queue of said email objects and where you implement methods like GetAllUnsentEmails() and AddEmail (which you use in the code from earlier instead of SendEmail)..